# Capybara Ruby Selenium-WebDriver checking for dialog not present

Tags: ruby, selenium

The code is for checking if the dialog "exists" is:

```
def loaded?
    if @window == nil
      result = false
    else
      result = @window.exists?
    end
    result
end
```

Problem is that when I use something like:

```
if (on(ImportErrorDialog).loaded?)
```

and the dialog is not present, the code pauses for around 1 minute before continuing (but works fine). I need it to return much faster than that, but I don't know where it's getting the timeout from.  It's not `Capybara.default_wait_time` (which is set  to '2' for us).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
def loaded?
    begin
        result = @window.displayed?
    rescue
        result = false
    end
    result
end
```

Have you tried using implicit waits?  You could put this in the code that returns `@window`, modifying the find_element to find the dialog.

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
wait.until { driver.find_element(:id => "some-dynamic-element") }
```

Comment: Thanks Richard.  I tried your code, and exactly the same thing is happening. The test pauses for about one minute on the @window.display?, when the window is not present.